# Asp.Net MVC Routing с несколькими необязательными параметрами

Tags: asp.net-mvc, маршрутизация

Только начал эксперименты с роутингом. Есть такая конструкция:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "1",
                    "{controller}/{1}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "2",
                    "{controller}/{2}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "3",
                    "{controller}/{3}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "12",
                    "{controller}/{1}/{2}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "13",
                    "{controller}/{1}/{3}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "23",
                    "{controller}/{2}/{3}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "123",
                    "{controller}/{1}/{2}/{3}",
                    new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action" }
                    );
```

Идея понятна: сделать так, чтобы удаление в строке (или не отправление в строку) одного или нескольких параметров (в том числе в середине) не приводило к ошибкам.

Когда параметра 3 это небольшая проблема, но стоит их увеличить хоть вдвое, так это требует уже гораздо большего кода. Разумеется, речь в конечном счете идет о предсказуемом числе параметров.

Возможно я в упор не вижу более эффективного способа сгенерировать корректный роутинг.

П.С.: Если интересует, то использую такой роутинг для гибкого фильтра интернет-магазина: таким образом строка лишается упоминания лишних умолчаний, выглядит более аккуратной и ЧПУ-шной.

Comment: так как в параметрах не важен порядок параметров, лучше использовать querystring вместо основной части url

Comment: @Grundy порядок параметров предпочтителен. А по поводу querystring — ни разу не сталкивался с этим понятием. Намного сложнее простой настройки роутинга?

Comment: наоборот: querystring - это часть идущая после `?` параметры которые есть в action, но нет в роуте берутся как раз оттуда

Comment: @Grundy а вам не составит труда в отдельном ответе расписать примерно, как будет выглядеть предложенный вами вариант решения моей задачи? Мой вариант меня устраивает, пока речь не заходит об отдельном расписывании /{1}/{2}/{3}/{4} и т. д.